# Will original Wii Graphics become HD on Wii U

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u

I know that Wii-U will work with the original Wii games and hardware.

When I play original Wii games on the Wii-U will the game graphics up convert to 720p/1080p? Or will the system play them in standard definition 480p?

Comment: The system isn't even out yet.  This is speculation.

Comment: This meta post should address your points: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/why-this-question-is-bad-for-this-site.  Essentially, without being the creator of the device, we can't give a definitive answer.  Questions about upcoming releases (games or gaming devices) are off-topic.

Comment: Now that the system is out, how is this a closed question?

Comment: I've voted re-open

Comment: As a side note, if you want HD Wii games, you can play them on an emulator. However, since games were not designed for HD, it might not work for every one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nintendo made [official statements](http://www.1up.com/news/wii-games-wont-look-nicer-wii-u) about this last year in interviews that **no, Wii U will not upscale Wii games.** Those interviews date back to the console's original reveal, but as far as I know, Nintendo's stance on that issue hasn't changed since.

Comment: Not that upscaling on the console would've changed anything, the TV does that anyway. To make a difference the video would have to be rendered in a higher internal resolution.